# Subversion Branching Question with Multiple Branches

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

We have the following structure in our Subversion repo:

[image: SVN Branch Example]
Here is a quick summary:

1. We started from the trunk and created branch 1.
2. We then created branch 2 from branch 1.
3. We then created 2 more branches off of branch 2.

So currently we have 4 branches nested off of the trunk.

**What I would like to do is reintegrate branch 2 into branch 1, delete branch 2, reintegrate branch 1 into the trunk, and delete branch 1.**

However, will doing this cause some sort of tree conflict on the b2a and b2b branches that were originally branched off of branch 2?  What is the preferred approach to accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't cause "some sort of tree conflict."

It is perfectly ok to do this, but I cannot comment on whether this is the way to go for you without knowing your exact scenario

Comment: I said "some sort of tree conflict" because we've run into issue with tree conflicts before and couldn't find the source of it.